# Parsing HTML with Python. requests and LXML

Tags: python, html, xpath, python-requests

So I'm trying to parse an HTML page to extract two pieces of data from an unordered list.

There are thousands of `<li>` elements in the page which have the following structure ...

```
            <li>
            <a href="/lesson/check/119" target="_blank">
                Check lesson <b>#119</b> "structure-of-the-blood-vessels"
            </a>
        </li>
```

This is the Python code I have got so far ...

```
import requests
from lxml import html

auth = {
  'user_login_form[_username]'      : 'USERNAME',
  'user_login_form[_plainPassword]' : 'PASSWORD',
  'user_login_form[csrf_token]'     : 'TOKEN'
  }

login_url = 'https://example.com/login'
page_url = 'https://example.com/lesson/list'

session = requests.Session()

p = session.post(
  login_url,
  data=auth
  )

print('Connecting to site ...',p.ok)

r = session.get(
  page_url
  )

print('Connecting to page ...',r.ok)

# Parsing text of the webpage into a DOM tree
tree = html.fromstring(r.text)
collection = tree.xpath('//li/a/descendant::text()')

for element in collection:
  print(element)
```

... and the output I get from this is ...

```
                Check lesson 
#106
 "functions-of-the-skeleton-4"


                Check lesson 
#107
 "classification-of-bones-1"
```

... etc.

The output I want from the script is ...

```
106,functions-of-the-skeleton-4
```

I then want to follow the URL from each `<li><a>` tag to grab a single piece of information from that page ...

```
    <h1 class="head-h1" style="padding: 1%;">Lesson #106 - Functions of the Skeleton</h1>
```

... so the final line of data generated by the script is ...

```
106,functions-of-the-skeleton-4,Functions of the Skeleton
```

Basically, I'm trying to make sure that the 'slug' for the lesson on the first page is the same as the lesson title on the child page.

Please can you help with the XPATH / Python?

Comment: BeautifulSoup is the recommended way of parsing HTML in python https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Comment: Thank you Iain - I would like to accomplish this with XPATH at the moment - BeautifulSoup is next on my list to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the XPath part. For each a element :

Generate the first part of your final line with :

```
concat(//b,",",translate(normalize-space(//a/text()[2]),'"',""),",")
```

(Output : 106,functions-of-the-skeleton-4,).

Store the value of //b/text (#106) in an object ('foo' for example).
Then on the 2nd page, get what you need with

```
normalize-space(substring-after(//h1[contains(.,{foo})],"-"))
```

(Output : Functions of the Skeleton). 
Concat the two previous results to get your final line of data.

Comment: Brilliant - thank you for the hints and tips on this.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help - after a little trial and error with the Python code, I've managed to get it to work perfectly (replacing the last part of the Python code above)...

```
# Parsing text of the webpage into a DOM tree
tree = html.fromstring(r.text)
collection = tree.xpath('//li') # collection of all li tags

for element in collection:
  lesson_no = element.xpath('substring-after(a/b,"#")') # lesson number
  slug = element.xpath('translate(normalize-space(a/text()[2]),\'"\',"")') # slug
  subpage_url = 'https://example.com'+element.xpath('a/@href')[0] # subpage
  s = session.get(subpage_url) # connect to subpage
  subpage_title = html.fromstring(s.text).xpath('substring-after(//h1/text()," - ")') # title
  line = lesson_no + ',' + slug + ',' + subpage_title
  print(line)
```

... prints ...

```
106,functions-of-the-skeleton-4,Functions of the Skeleton
107,classification-of-bones-1,Classification of Bones
108,structure-of-the-skeleton-1,Structure of the Skeleton
109,classification-of-joints-3,Classification of Joints
110,movement-patterns-2,Movement Patterns
```

Wonderful! My boss will be pleased!
Mark